How to Display arXiv ID with abbrvnat Bibliography Style in LaTeX?
I am using the following LaTeX code with the abbrvnat bibliography style to include an article from arXiv:
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{LIGOScientific:2024elc,
    author = "Abac, A. G. and others",
    collaboration = "LIGO Scientific, VIRGO, KAGRA",
    title = "{Observation of Gravitational Waves from the Coalescence of a $2.5-4.5~M_\odot$ Compact Object and a Neutron Star}",
    eprint = "2404.04248",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
    reportNumber = "LIGO-P2300352",
    month = "4",
    year = "2024"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{doi: \detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
test \citet{LIGOScientific:2024elc}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}

However, the arXiv ID is not displayed in the bibliography. I need to use the abbrvnat style format. Is there a way to automatically show the arXiv ID without editing each reference manually?

In contrast to biblatex, you cannot change what a bibtex style supports from the latex preamble.
